# Add properties to exisitng class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, properties

I have a simple class as shown :

```
Public Class myclass

Public Property myfont() As String
        Get
            Return m_myfont
        End Get
        Set
            m_myfont = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_myfont As String

End Class
```

This is how I'm calling my class from another webapp

```
Dim myfont as new myclass
myfont.fontname = "Arial"
```

Upto this is fine.

Now I would like to predefine some fonts and call them as :

```
myfont.fontsize = "It should display as shown in the below image"
```

[image]

How should I do to display all the predefined fonts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is called Enum:

```
Public Enum FontSize
    AsUnit
    Large
    Larger
End Enum
```

Define it in some class (e.g. "CommonTypes"), then add a property to `myClass`:

```
Private _myFontSize As FontSize
Public Property MyFontSize() As FontSize
    Get
        Return _myFontSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As FontSize)
        _myFontSize = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And you are good to go.

More about Enums [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-vbnet).

Comment: This is a perfectly valid answer so upvoted, but I don't think there's any need to define the enum in a common types class...it is already defined as part of the UI.Controls class, only need to set the property's type as FontSize

Comment: @soohoonigan Thank you, maybe I wasn't clear, but I wasn't suggesting to define the `Enum` type, but "a" `Enum`, so that the `Enum FontSize` could be shared among different classes...